# App settings not Connect Local database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently Working MVC5 project. Previous Project  working hosted database .i have created database local i have insert user value login .after create local database i am trying to connect its login not  working .  HomeSqlDBRepository using to read string database  value 
Here Login method Login code

```
 public class LoginRepository
    {
        HomeSqlRepository _repository = new HomeSqlRepository();
        public async Task<LoginModelViewModel> ValidateLogin(LoginModel model) {
            model.ThrowIfNull();
            var ConnectionString = AppSettingsReader.ReadString("thenna");
            IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dictionary.Add("username", model.UserEmail);
            dictionary.Add("password", model.Password);
            return await _repository.GetItemAsync<LoginModelViewModel>("dbo.validateuser", dictionary);
        }
        public async Task<LoginModelViewModel> GetProfileDetails(int uid)
        {
            var ConnectionString = AppSettingsReader.ReadString("thenna");
            IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dictionary.Add("uid", uid);
            return await _repository.GetItemAsync<LoginModelViewModel>("dbo.GetUserProfile", dictionary);
        }
```

homesqlrepository

```
public abstract class HomeSqlDBRepository
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = AppSettingsReader.ReadString("thenna");
        const int MaxItemCount = 1000;
        public enum SqlExecuteType
        {
            Scalar, NonQuery, Reader
        }
        public async Task<string> ExecuteSqlAsync(string procname, SqlExecuteType executiontype, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            string ret = "";

            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procname, sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in parameters)
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    if (executiontype == SqlExecuteType.Scalar)
                        ret = (await sqlCmd.ExecuteScalarAsync()).ToString();
                    else if (executiontype == SqlExecuteType.NonQuery)
                        ret = (await sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()).ToString();
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
            }
```

Appsettings config

```
  <add key="thenna" value="server=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;database=montage;user id=sa;password=root;trusted_connection=false;" />-



  <add key="CustomAuthentication.LoginUrl" value="/Account/LogOn" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Name" value=".CUSTOM_AUTH" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Expiration" value="1" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Timeout" value="20" />
```

AppSettingsReader using  cloud configuration manager

```
 public static class AppSettingsReader
    {
        public static string ReadString(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key).ToString();
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

where i did mistake  login not Working  . what cloud configuration manager ? why  using this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Any particular error or exception?

Comment: return null value  @Alex  no error throw  but i can able login after connect server  its login after comment server db and  uncomment local  then  press ctrl+f5  that time worked